# 5.71.1 for Wordpress doesn't download

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I'm on Civi 5.50.1 on two different sites and should really upgrade.  As Civi gets more complex, my fear of upgrading goes up.  Seems like more problems every time.  Anyway, problem right off the bat.  It won't let me download 5.71.1-wordpress.zip.  It starts the download and just sits there.  5.71.0 downloads just fine.

UPDATE: I upgraded to 5.71.0. It went fine, but I can't send email blasts now.  CiviMail Components Settings is showing an error:
[image]
Line 37: echo smarty_function_help(array('id'=>$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['fieldSpec']->value['help']['id'],'file'=>$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['fieldSpec']->value['help']['file']),$_smarty_tpl);

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Which PHP-version do you use?

Comment: 8.2.  The next day, the download button for 5.71.1 was working again.

Answer (score 1):

The inability to download 5.71.1 seemed to be a one-day glitch. Regarding the upgrade, I ended up having to start over.  Upgraded to 5.70.2, but still having problems ;-(